# My diagram is indented right although I centered it

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

So I was trying to draw a tikz picture

So in my `begin{document}`, I have written

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{\input{ball_MSD.tikz}\unskip}
    \caption{Mass Spring Damper system at $t=t_1$}
\end{figure}
```

and in `ball_MSD.tikz`, I have put

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,
                 decorations.pathmorphing,
                 decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    force/.style={>=latex,draw=blue,fill=blue},
    displacement/.style={>=latex,draw=brown,fill=brown},
    plane/.style={draw=black,fill=blue!10},
]

    \tikzstyle{spring}=[minimum width = 1cm,decorate,decoration={zigzag, pre length=0.2cm,post length=0.2cm,segment length=3}]

    \tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,mark connection node=dmp,mark=at position 0.5 with 
    {
        \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.25cm,draw=none] {};
        \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
        \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
    }}, decorate]

    \node[name=s,shape=rectangle,fill=black!30, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2cm] at (0cm,1.5cm) {};
    \draw[plane] (-2cm,0) to (2cm,0);
    \draw[force,->] (s.center) -- ++(0cm,-2.5cm) node[right, near end] {$F_w=mg$};
    \draw[spring] ($(s.south) - (0.75cm,0)$) -- ($(0,0) - (0.75cm,0)$);
    \draw[damper] ($(s.south) + (0.75cm,0)$) -- ($(0,0) + (0.75cm,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Although I have centered my code, the `tikzpicture` is shifted towards the right whilst the `caption` is not.

[image: The caption is centered, but the tikzpicture is not]

There are no error messages and I am using the `memoir` class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should only use `\usetikzlibrary` in the preamble.

Comment: my `tikzpicture` depends on the things that I put in my preamble though

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. Please add a compilable `main.tex` from `\documentclass{memoir}` to `\end{document}`   (test it before posting)